# android webview rendering is showing a White Page

Tags: android, android-webview

Sometimes, when I load my webview with loadUrl, the website is not showing up until I touch the screen or scroll.

It's like I have a webview drawing problem.

```
            Context context = ctx;
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.website);
            WebView webView = (WebView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.weburl);
            webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);  
            //Disable the horizontal scroll bar  
            webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);  
            //Enable JavaScript  
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
            //Set the user agent  
            webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("AndroidWebView");  
            //Clear the cache  
            webView.clearCache(true);  


            webView.loadUrl("http://" + WebUrl);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                    // do your handling codes here, which url is the requested url
                    // probably you need to open that url rather than redirect:
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return false; // then it is not handled by default action
               }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.refreshDrawableState();
                    Log.v("FINISH","FINISH");
                }


            });
```

Do anybody have an idea why I have this kind of problem.

Comment: in WebViewClient(), think you should `return true;` as in your host application (view) handles the [url](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html).

Comment: @Jean-Francois, can post your full code?

Comment: Could it be a problem with the website you're loading? If it is not sensitive, show the url.

Comment: Yes, if you can post your full code, we can use it to try to duplicate the problem, which would definitely help with the troubleshooting.  As also mentioned, if it's happening with particular URLs, it would help to know that, and, if possible, which URLs.

Comment: Tested using above code it working fine do you have active internet connection in your test environment ?

Answer (score 2):

What version of Android are you testing on? Pre-4.1 versions of Android seem to have this sort  problem with WebViews sometimes.

Add this to the manifest for that Activity to fix the problem:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

Comment: Disabling the Hardware Acceleration is not a good thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

Make `WebView` invisible in your layout:

```
<WebView
    ...
    android:visibility="invisible"
    .../>
```

Now, show it back when `onPageFinished` occurs for the fist time:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if (webView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure, I don't have the whole code, but I think is related to the `webViewClient` implemented in this function:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
    // do your handling codes here, which url is the requested url
    // probably you need to open that url rather than redirect:
    view.loadUrl(url);
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    return false; // then it is not handled by default action
}
```

here is the officiel definition:

[public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)

Try to test with your code without implementing `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, or make it `return true`.