# White screen partially covers my content in webview android

Tags: android, webview

I am developing a hybrid application for android.
In my code I have only webview.

When I try to run the app, I get a white rectangle that covers almost all the content of the url. [This is how it looks](http://nesjeck.net/nesjeck/images/err.png)

Tried almost everything, no success.

This is my "MainActivity.java" code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
  //  String url = "http://shop.chefnoded.co.il";
    String url = "http://myurl";
    WebView view = (WebView)this.findViewById((R.id.webView1));
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    view.loadUrl(url);


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

This is activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.mywv.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"

>

<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

How do I get rid of this white rectangle?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

}

This is the part that was automatically generated by google dev. studio.
After I removed it, the white screen dissapeared.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I tested the code with my Samsung Galaxy S4 (API level 18) and it worked perfectly, I suspect it has to do with the device or the API level. Did you try adding

`android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`

to your activity in the manifest file as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414672/android-webview-rendering-is-showing-a-white-page)?

Also, what device + API level are you testing it on?

Answer (score -1):

How do I get rid of the white rectangle on my S4?

I'm not sure how to make the changes that you guys are talking about with codes and domains etc.

The box is irritating since I did the Kit-Kat update. Help!